# Splitting string by space not returns all of the elements

Tags: scala, scala-collections

When I tried to split a string based on the space as a delimiter, and then apply the contains method on it like below

```
"no EJAVA here".contains("JAVA")
res0: Boolean = true
```

For that string when I tried using string_var.contains("JAVA") then it returns true, but when I tried it using

```
"no EJAVA here".split(" ").contains("JAVA")
res1: Boolean = false
```

then it returns false, is the Array[String] searches the complete elements of the array or matches substrings insides the individual elements?

Comment: How about `string_var.split(" ").exists(e => e.contains("JAVA"))` ?

Comment: Please read about how to write [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for StackOverflow. In particular creating [MCV examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No one is going to read through those huge blocks. You should find a neater way to explain your problem

Comment: @jwvh thanks, I will take into consideration next time before asking any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test in the REPL demonstrates the problem.

```
scala> "no EJAVA here".contains("JAVA")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> "no EJAVA here".split(" ").contains("JAVA")
res1: Boolean = false
```

The `contains()` method on a `String` will look for any sub-string, but the `contains()` method on an `Array[String]` will only match on individual elements of the array, not sub-strings within the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning all the split strings. The reason it does not find "JAVA" is because no element in the array containing the split strings is equal to `JAVA` . Although, if you type:

```
 string_var.split(" ").contains("""JAVA",[http://collaboratory.emsl.pnl.gov/docs/collab/sam/CodeStandards.html""")
```

, you will get:

```
res: Boolean = true
```